# in VSC, which FTP extension is best for auto-uploading to remote on save?

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code, autosave

I used to use Sublime text and paid for a donation plugin that perfectly uploaded when i saved a file, to my remote FTP.

Now, i have switched to Visual Studio Code and having trouble getting that same functionality. I currently am trying two FTP extensions - ftp-sync and ftp-simple. Neither of these seem to auto-upload to my FTP without me having to click through extra steps, like to specify which remote FTP of the few I have in config, and / or remote folder.

I was looking for any advice on

1. If i am doing it incorrectly - maybe something to do with workspace in VSC - is there a way to inform VSC which local folder goes with which remote server / folder?
2. Which FTP extension can do this.To make sure i am clear, what I need is when i save a file in VSC, it instantly pushes it to the remote FTP in the same folder, without needing anything from me besides the save.

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, SFTP is so far very easy to setup and use. It loads your remote directories in VS Code and lets you edit and save them directly on the remote server.

Check it out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: unfortunately, it has to download the remote folders first to the local PC :(

Comment: This extension is depreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a plugin that does this, and this is it: [ftp-kr at VSC Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ruakr.ftp-kr)

It will automatically upload to server without any extra clicks or prompts on save and more in Visual Studio Code. You do have to configure it to do so, but it is working for me.